# How to pass some extra dynamic data between angular routes?

Tags: angular

How to pass some extra data between angular routes:

```
  navigateToItem(item: Item) {
    this.router.navigate(
      ['itemss', item.name],
      { state: { data: { id: item.id } } }
    );
  }
```

Seems like we can pass `Navigation Extras` like in the above method.

But how can I access this in the target route.

I'm also using `ngrx-router-store`. (if this can also be done with ngrx router store, please suggest that also, but not necessary)

If passing some extra dynamic data apart from `params` or `queryparams` please suggest that. (cause I don't wanna display the extra params like `id` or any extra data in the url fragment.)

So I need to pass them and access them like above

Comment: I'm not sure why angular don't have such a mechanism to pass some extra hidden data(ie. which are not shown in the url string) between routes (rather than using services), even react and vue has this ability.

Answer (score 0):

The [getCurrentNavigation](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#getcurrentnavigation) function exposed in Router is what you're looking for. Make sure you call this in the constructor of the component you're navigating to, or else the information wont be there. (I think you can still access it from the history though)

Preferred method would be:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.itemId= this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.data.id;
}
```

Comment: I've tried that also... But it is only has one key value pair ```{replaceUrl: true}``` nothing else!!

Comment: @mex As long as you're calling this from the constructor the information should be present. Could you provide a stackblitz link recreating the issue?

Comment: Yes. I'm calling this from the constructor... I'm not sure what's happening...

Comment: Could you try accessing via `this.itemId=history.state.data.id`

Comment: Yes.... this is the method I use instead, it works... but I don't like this... I thought angular would have a mechanism for this... but seems like we have to stick vanilla js